# How do I embed a python plot chart (or image) in ppt and refresh it

Tags: python, plot, embed, powerpoint

I can open a ppt. file with win32com, just unsure how to select the slide and insert an image in it, here is what I have:

```
def createppt():
width=10
height=10
x=10
y=10
Image = ABFLgraph()
ppt = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
ppt.Visible = True
pptfile = ppt.Presentations.Open(file2,ReadOnly=0,Untitled=0, WithWindow=1)
Base = pptfile.Slides(2)
pic = Base.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename =Image,
    LinkToFile=True,
    SaveWithDocument=False,
    Left=x, Top=y,
    Width=width, Height=height)
```

Any suggestions? In the Base = pptfile.Slides(2) I was trying to select the slide number to insert the image into but this didnt work...I get this Error:

File ">", line 5, in AddPicture
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "The specified file wasn't found.", None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Which I think means that there is an issue with how I am passing the filename/image.

Comment: http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/ is very nice simple example of PPT COM automation from Python. If you are having with figuring out how the specific steps of image embedding via COM, you should probably show your existing code so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your plots as image files (using pylab.savefig(), presuming you're using matplotlib), then add them to your PowerPoint slide calling slides.addpicture(). Example syntax for the addpicture function is available in the following iPython notebook: [Automating Microsoft Office with Python](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/sanand0/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/Office.ipynb).

Comment: Here I reedited the question to show you the code I have been using. Your original link helped but still cant get the image in there.

Comment: Actually I saved the plots as png images instead. Worked perfectly!